# Can the delivery address be hidden in SagePay?

Tags: opayo

Our client is an online service-based company for which a delivery address is not required so they would like to hide the shipping address on the SagePay payment pages.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are using the Server iframe solution, then the addresses will never be shown to the consumer. If that is not the case, then you could customise the template (card_confirmation.xslt) to not display the address.....

Comment: We're not currently using customised templates unfortunately, but thanks for pointing out that it's possible to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a hosted solution such as Form or Server integration you can switch your template to No Address.

You can follow this guide on the Sage Pay website on how to activate customised payment pages.

Its for customised templates but its the same process for switching to no address.

https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/12/38/activating-customised-payment-pages